# Web SQL database version error on insertion of 2nd record

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I had a html form where employee record is inserted, on submitting record it just save on browser database i.e. websql but it giving me error "unable to open database, version mismatch, '1.0' does not match the currentVersion of ''"
on insertion of 2nd record.
Please give suggestion to resolve this.

following is the code I had done for it.

```
function myfunction() {
        debugger;
        var obj = {};
        obj.first_name = $("#txtFirstName").val();
        obj.last_name = $("#txtLastName").val();
        obj.qualification = $("#txtQualication").val();
        obj.age = $("#txtAge").val();

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            //websql supported
            var localstorage = openDatabase('dbemp', '1.0', 'employess database', 2 * 1024 * 1024, function () {
                console.log("created/found database");
            });

            var success = function () {
                $("#txtFirstName").val("");
                $("#txtLastName").val("");
                $("#txtQualication").val("");
                $("#txtAge").val("");
            };

            var failure = function () {
                alert('records don\'t save');
            };

            localstorage.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (first_name, last_name, qualification, age)', function () {
                    console.log("created table");
                }, function () {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO employee (first_name, last_name, qualification, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                    [obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.qualification, obj.age],success,failure);
                    console.log("Insert record successfully..");
                    alert('Record Save locally');
                });
            });

        } else {
            console.log("NOT SUPPORTED");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your localstorage is in fact the Web SQL database of your browser. The problem your having is that you are trying to open an already created database with a version '' now with a different version '1.0'. Changing the version number should do the trick